# How to select menu item from Chrome Context menu using Selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, contextmenu

I am using VBA and Selenium and I want to select a menu item on a Chrome Context menu. The context menu is displayed using the below VBA code but the sendkeys doesn't move the cursor down on the context menu.

```
bot.Actions.ClickContext(bot.FindElementById("chTrend")).SendKeys(bot.Keys.Down).SendKeys(bot.Keys.Down).Perform
```

[This is the context menu that is displayed with the above code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHLZn.jpg)
I want to select "Save Image" (2nd option) from the Chrome context menu.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Anyone, I will really appreciate any help with this issue. Thanking in advance.

Comment: you're outside of the DOM at that point. You could take a screenshot.